# Group By Unidirection with GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a fairly common pair of models:

```
class Parent {
    static hasMany = [children: Child]
}

class Child {
    String someProperty
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is perform a group by Child.someProperty, but I haven't been too successful on View.

In the controller, I can do:

```
def children = parentInstance.children.groupBy{child -> child.someProperty}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is recursively display children under each `someProperty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my own problem. I simplified the functionality by simply adding a method to the Parent model to return all children with the relative Parent id or instance sorted by the desired property.